# "Base class undefined."

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've got an error:

> error C2504: 'employee' : base class undefined.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

This is my first time working with inheritance in C++ and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. When I try to make a class that derives another, it says that the parent class is undefined, even though I have the header file of the parent class included. What could be the problem?

Main.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "manager.h"

int main()
{
manager ian;
ian.getdata();
ian.putdata();

return 0;
}
```

Manager.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "employee2.h"
#include "student.h"

class manager : private employee2, private student //Error happens here
{
    //Stuff
};
```

Student.h:

```
#pragma once
class student
{
    //Stuff
};
```

Employee2.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "employee.h"
class employee2 : employee
{
    //Stuff
};
```

It says that both the student class and the employee2 class are undefined. Also, the employee2 class inherits a class called employee, which also gets the same error. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's my student.cpp file. All the other .cpp files that I'm getting errors with look similar to this one.

```
#include "student.h"

void student::getedu(){
cout << "Enter name of school or university: ";
cin >> school;
cout << "Enter highest degree earned \n";
cout << "(Highschool, Bachelor's Master's, PhD)";
cin >> degree;
}

void student::putedu() const{
cout << "\n School or university: " << school;
cout << "\n Highest degree earned: " << degree;
}
```

Comment: Show the complete error messages please.

Comment: 1) I wouldn't use "private" inheritance unless you were really, really sure that's what you wanted.  Please change both subclasses: `class manager : public employee2, public student`  and `class employee2 : public employee`  2) Lose the "#pragma once".  Substitute `#ifdef employee2_h ...` etc

Comment: Where is `class employee`?... I see an `employee2`... no `employee`... Show `employee.h`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you are getting an "x is undefinied" based upon the code you showed. Actually, it appears you are using `#include` wrong.

```
#include employee.h
```

should be

```
#include "employee.h"
```

Other than that, other than the missing `employee` class you mention, and `manager` not having `getdata` and "`putdata` in your example, you code will compile fine.

Comment: Sorry, I typed that part manually in my post. It's all correct in the code.

Comment: In that case, your code compile fine using Visual Studio 2010. Can you post the error and compiler you are using? If it is still saying "x is undefined" then you may be missing .cpp files from your project, but your code compiles fine using VS2010.

Comment: error C2504: 'employee' : base class undefined. Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Perhaps this is happening due to a circular include (an include including the same include that is including itself). There is nothing in your code provided that would give that error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, there are empty spaces at the end of each file.
Before compilation process the files are concatinated and your pragma could be deactivated because of sth like this:

```
}#pragma once
```

the '}' comes from the previously included file.

That could be a reason. Besides, the code looks, like it should be compilable.

Comment: Can someone confirm that this could actually happen? It seems rather easy for a compiler avoid doing that

Comment: Why should the pre-compiler insert something, what the user probably did't want? I saw code, where this was used as a feature. Can't remember why, was an ugly hack of a "clever" programmer. This used to produce more harm than use. Therefore some compilers reported a missing end-line in a file as a bug.